# Convert a List to a file list to use in an arcpy tool

Tags: python, arcpy, list

I just can't figure out how to feed a list of files into an arcpy tool...

I have

```
 List_tif.append(os.getcwd()+"\\Stage1\\"+name+"\\GeoTif\\"+name+"_"+str(ddp.pageRow.PageName) + ".tif;")
```

That generates the list and then I try to feed it into arcpy

```
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(List_tif,os.getcwd()+"\\Stage2\\jp2", name+"_tif.jp2", "90019.prj", "", "", "3", "LAST","FIRST")
```

but I get an error as the tools is expecting file1.tif; file2.tif etc but is getting a List

> 'P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\Stage1\LS\GeoTif\LS_O10.png;',
>   'P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\Stage1\LS\GeoTif\LS_O11.png;',
>   'P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\Stage1\LS\GeoTif\LS_O12.png;',
>   'P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\Stage1\LS\GeoTif\LS_O13.png;']

I tried

```
PNGList=string.split(List_png, ";")
```

but this doesn't work either. This should be simple (:-

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks guys...I tried the list rasters as well but it doesn't even generate the list

```
>>> rasters=arcpy.ListRasters('*')
>>> rasters
>>> files=arcpy.ListFiles()
>>> files
>>> import glob
>>> rasters=glob.glob('*.png')
>>> rasters
['BA25k_A2.png', 'BA25k_A3.png', 'BA25k_A4.png', 'BA25k_A5.png', 'BA25k_A6.png', 'BA25k_A7.png', 'BA25k_A8.png', 'BA25k_B10.png', 'BA25k_B11.png', 'BA25k_B2.png', 'BA25k_B3.png', 'BA25k_B4.png', 'BA25k_B5.png', 'BA25k_B6.png', 'BA25k_B7.png', 'BA25k_B8.png', 'BA25k_B9.png', 'BA25k_C10.png', 'BA25k_C11.png', 'BA25k_C12.png', 'BA25k_C2.png', 'BA25k_C3.png', 'BA25k_C4.png', 'BA25k_C5.png', 'BA25k_C6.png', 'BA25k_C7.png', 'BA25k_C8.png', 'BA25k_C9.png', 'BA25k_D10.png', 'BA25k_D11.png', 'BA25k_D12.png', 'BA25k_D13.png', 'BA25k_D2.png', 'BA25k_D3.png', 'BA25k_D4.png', 'BA25k_D5.png', 'BA25k_D6.png']
>>>
```

I didn't mean to ask this specifically for the arcpy mosaic tool as passing the list of files is important for lots of other tools as well such as creating a mosaic dataset, filling a gdb etc.

I also tried your vtab example

```
vtab = arcpy.ValueTable(1)
for tif in List_tif:
    vtab.addRow(tif)

print "Generating jp2 from png tiles @"+str(datetime.datetime.now())
##PNGList=string.split(List_png, ";")
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(vtab,os.getcwd()+"\\Stage2\\jp2", name+"_tif.jp2", "90019.prj", "", "", "3", "LAST","FIRST")
```

but I still get the bands error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get arcpy.MosiacToNewRaster to work with list](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32617/cannot-get-arcpy-mosiactonewraster-to-work-with-list)

Comment: If its not a duplicate perhaps update Question to say why answer(s) there don't provide a solution here

Comment: Please see my updated question...it was supposed to be more general on passing files into arcpy tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you remembering to set your [`arcpy.env.workspace`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000002000000) before using the various arcpy list functions (`ListRaster`, `ListFiles`, etc.)?

Also many arcpy functions **do** take Python list objects for some arguments. They are denoted in the help by syntax such as `[input_raster,...]`. Indeed, [`MosaicToNewRaster`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000098000000)'s `input_rasters` argument does.

There may be other functions that require a semicolon-delimited string instead. You can easily create one using `';'.join(myList)`, for example.

You could also greatly simplify and make more robust your path building code by taking advantage of [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and string formatting (either the [newer `.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#new-string-formatting) or the [older modulo (`%`) method)](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) instead of using the concatentation operator (`+`) and hardcoding `\\`'s everywhere.

Your second line doesn't work because in your first line you are conflating the two methods (passing a list and passing a semicolon-delimited list). Thus you are a building a list of strings, each string having a semicolon at the end, which is not a valid pathname. It would probably work if you just removed the `;` at the end of your first line.

Your third line doesn't work because you want to join, not split the list. It might seem counterintuitive, but I recommend reading Dive Into Python's [Joining Lists and Splitting Strings](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/joining_lists.html) section for a better explanation.

Comment: I had mistakenly done "arcpy.env=os.getcwd()" rather than "arcpy.env.workspace=os.getcwd()" and so the arcpy.List* didn't work. Once this was corrected merge worked fine. Thanks for your time...